# Http call is RPC?

Tags: http, rpc

As usual, we surf the internet using http protocol with firefox,chrome browser,such as we visit stackoverlow by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, we get the rendered page, stackoverflow is process A, and our browser is process B.is this the RPC call?

Comment: Hi lawrence, is your question still unanswered?

Answer (score 3):

RPC means giving the illusion of calling a procedure (method) whose implementation is in a process distinct from the caller.  HTTP itself does not provide that illusion.  The typical case of a browser requesting HTML from a server is not an RPC call.

However, RPC technologies can be built atop HTTP, where a remote method invocation is implemented as an HTTP request, and returning the method's results is implemented via the HTTP response.

Answer (score 2):

Your example describes not a RPC call it describes a REST call.

The URI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask (unfortunately the name of the resource was not a good choice) is the resource (not a process) and through a HTTP method your are manipulate or request the resource. So REST is all about resources whereas RPC is about operations/procedures/methods.

A RPC call is also possible with HTTP. Always when you are using a HTTP to call an operation it's RPC. This is called

> WYGOPIAO: What You GET Or POST Is An Operation

JSON-RPC uses The HTTP methods GET or POST to call an method/operation/procedure by sending an JSON encoded string. The example below shows the JSON-RPC object to call the method echo.

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "echo", "params": ["hello world"], "id": 0}
```